# How to get selected indexPath.section and indexPath.row value in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, row, tableview

I have insert 2 section and 2 rows in tableview, then i tried to get selected section and row value using `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but i have to get only `indexPath.section` value, i want both section and row value. Is it possible to do that? please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

//    Add the PatientName Label

    UILabel *cellTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 7, 300, 30)];
    cellTitle.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cellTitle.tag = indexPath.section;
    [cellTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cellTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]];
    [cellTitle setText:[[cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellTitle];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *labelTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [labelTap addTarget:self action:@selector(viewPatient:)];
    [labelTap setDelegate:nil];
    [labelTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [cellTitle addGestureRecognizer:labelTap]; // cellTitle add here
    [labelTap release];
}

-(void)viewPatient:(id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *lSender = sender;
    UILabel *lObjLabel = (UILabel *)[lSender view];
    NSLog(@"tag:%d",lObjLabel.tag); // only get indexpath.section value
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code..

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:
[[sender superview] tag]];
```

Answer (score 0):

write this line..

```
[cellTitle setText:[[cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
```

instead of

```
[cellTitle setText:[[cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```